# Uploading large files to server

Tags: web-services, server, ftp

The project I'm working on logs data on distributed devices that needs to be joined in a single database on a remote server.

The logs cannot be streamed as they are recorded (network may not be available etc) so they must be sent in bulky 0.5-1GB text based csv files occasionally.

As far as I understand this means having a web service receive the data in form of post requests is out of the question because of file sizes.

So far I've come up with this approach: Use some file transfer protocol (ftp or similar) to upload files from device to server. Devices would have to figure out a unique filename to do this with. Have the server periodically check for new files, process them by committing them to the database and deleting them afterwards.

It seems like a very naive way to go about it, but simple to implement.

However, I want to avoid any pitfalls before I implement any specifics. Is this approach scaleable (more devices, larger files)? Implementation will either be done using a private/company owned server or a cloud service (Azure for instance) - will it work for different platforms?

Answer (score 0):

You could actually do this through web/http as well, after setting a higher value for post request in the web server (`post_max_size` and`upload_max_filesize` for PHP). This will allow devices to interact regardless of platform. Should't be too hard to make a `POST` request server from any device. A simple cURL request could get this job done.
FTP is also possible. Or SCP, to make it safer.

Either way, I think this does need some application on the server to be able to fetch and manage these files using a database. Perhaps a small web application? ;)

As for the unique name, you could use a combination of the device's unique ID/name along with current unix time. You could even hash this (md5/sh1) afterwards if you like.